# Remove duplicate key value from array of NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I need to compare two array values one by one, if any value match with one another, i need to update the value and replace it from main array.

**NSMutableArray** is having an array of **NSDictionary**

**NSArray** is having an array of **NSString** objects.

My code is

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicOne = @{@"eveId":@"1",@"imgArray":@[@"one",@"two"]};
    NSMutableDictionary *dicTwo = @{@"eveId":@"2",@"imgArray":@[@"Three",@"Four"]};
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [tempArray addObject:dicOne];
    [tempArray addObject:dicTwo];

    NSArray *eventArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
    NSString *fileName = @"Five";
    for (int jj = 0; jj<[eventArray count]; jj++) {
        NSString *topArrayEventId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[eventArray objectAtIndex:jj]];

        for (int kk = 0; kk<[tempArray count]; kk++) {
            NSMutableDictionary *curentObj = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:kk]mutableCopy];
            NSString *innerArrayEventId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[curentObj valueForKey:@"eveId"]];

            if ([innerArrayEventId isEqualToString:topArrayEventId]) {
                NSLog(@"update inner array and replace main array");

                NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                imgArray = [[curentObj objectForKey:@"imgArray"]mutableCopy];
                [imgArray addObject:fileName];
                [curentObj setObject:[imgArray mutableCopy] forKey:@"imgArray"];
                [tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:kk withObject:[curentObj mutableCopy]];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"add new object to main array");
                NSMutableDictionary*  storeData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [storeData setObject:topArrayEventId forKey:@"eveId"];
                NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                [imgArray addObject:fileName];
                [storeData setObject:imgArray forKey:@"imgArray"];
                [tempArray addObject:storeData];
            }

        }
    }
    NSLog(@"final updation------->%@",tempArray);
```

I want output like below

```
(
{
    eveId = 1;
    imgArray =     (
                    one,
                    two,
                    five
                    );
},
{
    eveId = 2;
    imgArray =     (
                    Three,
                    Four,
                    five
                    );
}
{
    eveId = 3;
    imgArray =     (
                    five

                    );
}
)
```

But i am not getting with that code..its giving wrong output. i having problem with inner loop.

Wrong output looks below

```
(
{
    eveId = 1;
    imgArray =     (
        one,
        two,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 2;
    imgArray =     (
        Three,
        Four,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 1;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 2;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 2;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 3;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 3;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 3;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 3;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
},
{
    eveId = 3;
    imgArray =     (
        Five,
        Five
    );
}
)
```

Comment: try using NSPredicate

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904295/remove-duplicate-from-nsmutablearray-containing-nsdictionary

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820376/removing-duplicates-of-a-key-value-from-an-array-of-dictionaries

Comment: are you checked my answer? now edited the answer check it out

Comment: I did it, thanks for the answer, i will give a try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicate method using to achieve this

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dicOne = @{@"eveId":@"1",@"imgArray":@[@"one",@"two"]};
NSMutableDictionary *dicTwo = @{@"eveId":@"2",@"imgArray":@[@"Three",@"Four"]};
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[tempArray addObject:dicOne];
[tempArray addObject:dicTwo];

NSArray *eventArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
NSString *fileName = @"Five";


for (int jj = 0; jj<[eventArray count]; jj++) {

    NSArray *resultArray = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.eveId = %@", [eventArray objectAtIndex:jj]]];
    NSString *topArrayEventId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[eventArray objectAtIndex:jj]];


    if([resultArray count]>0) {
    NSMutableDictionary *curentObj;
    NSString *innerArrayEventId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[resultArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"eveId"]];
    if ([innerArrayEventId isEqualToString:topArrayEventId]) {
    curentObj= [[resultArray objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    imgArray = [[[resultArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"imgArray"]mutableCopy];
    [imgArray addObject:fileName];
    [curentObj setObject:[imgArray mutableCopy] forKey:@"imgArray"];
    [tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:jj withObject:[curentObj mutableCopy]];
    }
    }
    else {
        NSMutableDictionary*  storeData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [storeData setObject:topArrayEventId forKey:@"eveId"];
        NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [imgArray addObject:fileName];
        [storeData setObject:imgArray forKey:@"imgArray"];
        [tempArray addObject:storeData];
    }

}
NSLog(@"final updation------->%@",tempArray);

 OutPut : 
final updation------->(
        {
        eveId = 1;
        imgArray =         (
            one,
            two,
            Five
        );
    },
        {
        eveId = 2;
        imgArray =         (
            Three,
            Four,
            Five
        );
    },
        {
        eveId = 3;
        imgArray =         (
            Five
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing NSMutableArray to use NSMutableSet

```
NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

with

```
NSMutableSet *imgSet = [NSMutableSet set];
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableset

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
for (int kk = 0; kk<[tempArray count]; kk++)
```

with

```
for (int kk = jj; kk<[tempArray count]; kk++)
```

now run the code, is it working now?